# VB6 "List & Label" control library

Tags: vb6, listlabel

I have a task to complile VB6 legacy project but I can't do this because of complilation errors which informs that some "**List & Label**" library is required..

Unfortanutely I google nothing something about it.. If you know something about this library, please let me know.. Perhapse it's full name or WEB site of f company who develops/supports it

File name of this library is **cm32L7.dll**

I would be grateful for any advice!
Thank you.

Comment: What is the file name of the library (DLL or OCX)? And could it be something written by one of your previous developers?

Comment: File name of the library is "cm32L7.dll" and unfortunately this project was written by our customer contractors and now we cannot communicate with them to know these details.. :(

Comment: If the original application is running on a machine somewhere, you should be able to pull the file off it.

Comment: Get the file onto your machine and register it. Start-Run `regsvr32 c:\somewhere\cm32L7.dll`

Comment: When you've got the file, check the version information to see who created it. Right click in Windows explorer and choose properties, version. This assumes the authors filled in the version info properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it [Combit List And Label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-List-Label-new-version/) ?

Googled based on Westie's link.

Answer (score 2):

This is combit List & Label and it seems that you are using the DLL-Interface and not the OCX. Your code is referencing Version 7 but the current version is List & Label 18. I would suggest asking the experts in the List & Label [forum](http://www.reporting-tool-forum.com/ListLabelUS/tabid/65/language/en-US/Default.aspx?g=topics&f=4)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but I did find a link on [this page](http://www.webhostingtalk.nl/archive/index.php/t-143727.html) which in turn points to a site called [zlib.net](http://zlib.net/).  It seems that the library in this case is related to some form of compression algorithm.  Don't know if this helps, but it's worth a try.